# gsl gnu solving first order ordinary differential equation

Tags: ode, gsl, differential-equations

I visited the gnu gsl website and i dont find the example there to solve a differential equation to be intuitive at all (especially because it is using 2nd order differential equation). https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/ODE-Example-programs.html#ODE-Example-programs
Can somebody guide about where to find a descriptive guide to how solve a very simple **first order** differetial equation.

For example, supoose my function is y'=x+2y (or any such function) then how do i write code in gsl to solve it with a given fixed step size and initial condition.

Comment: Is it a requirement that the solution be in C? Try the documentation for python `scipy.integrate.odeint`. -- Or just implement the Heun or RK4 fixed step-size loops in C as an educational exercise. Try to find an optimal step size for a given precision,... After that you will better appreciate why the interface for a general solver is so complex.

Comment: yeah .. the requirement  is in C .

Comment: Can you please give a example of a sample code which would do a very simple function such that y'=x+2y usin GSL ? Being totally new to this library I am not ale to infer a basic starting point for such a simple function as above.

Comment: Could you add additionally to your problems a more detailed task description, the general framework around the task in a few words, and what you expect to be the final results in numerical ODE solving in the near future?

Comment: The intention is to learn the solver for basic ODE before I jump on to the complex second order function. As I mentioned, I am looking forward to experiment with different step size and initial,final values of x and see how well the solution converges. All I need is y'=x+2y between x=0 to x=1 with initial condition (x,y)=(0,0) using gsl_odeiv2_step_rk1imp. Is there any way I can send you the code because the comment section does not allow me to paste my code since it is too long. Alternatively, I just now posted my code below as 'Answer' with a note to you so that you could review my code.

Comment: You should be able to edit the question to add code or other sections. Best to mark new sections with some kind of time stamp so that the time evolution is less confusing. If evolution of the question takes you too far from the original topic, open a new question and add links to it.

Comment: It is pointless to experiment with step sizes as the solver uses internal steps at optimized step sizes and interpolates the values at the requested output times. You could use the fixed step size methods, but then it would be instructional to implement all of the implicit Euler method by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `y'=f(x,y)=x+2y` the arrays have all dimension 1, which normally is something to avoid, but here it is instructional. For the explicit solvers, i.e., those not containing `imp` in the name, you do not need the Jacobian:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_errno.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_odeiv2.h>

int odefunc (double x, const double y[], double f[], void *params)
{
    f[0] = x+2*y[0];   
    return GSL_SUCCESS;
}


int * jac;

int main ()
{
    int dim = 1;
    gsl_odeiv2_system sys = {odefunc, NULL, dim, NULL};

    gsl_odeiv2_driver * d = gsl_odeiv2_driver_alloc_y_new (&sys, gsl_odeiv2_step_rkf45, 1e-6, 1e-6, 0.0);
    int i;
    double x0 = 0.0,  xf = 100.0; /* start and end of integration interval */
    double x = x0;
    double y[1] = { 1.0  };  /* initial value */

    for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        double xi = x0 + i * (xf-x0) / 100.0;
        int status = gsl_odeiv2_driver_apply (d, &x, xi, y);

        if (status != GSL_SUCCESS)
        {
            printf ("error, return value=%d\n", status);
            break;
        }

        printf ("%.8e %.8e\n", x, y[0]);
    }

    gsl_odeiv2_driver_free (d);
    return 0;
}
```

You may want to look up the book *"Introduction to Computational Modeling Using C and Open-Source Tools"* by Jose M. Garrido.

Comment: Hi LutzL,Your program indeed is an immensely helpful resource for a beginner like me. Thank you! Kindly advise about the following questions I have:    **(1)**. Suppose my step size is 0.25 and I want to evaluate from x=0 to x=1, I suppose I have to run the for loop from i=1 to i=4 (since 1-0/0.25=4). Is that correct?     **(2)** I was hoping to use the **gsl_odeiv2_step_rk1imp** function. If I replace the function **gsl_odeiv2_step_rkf45** by **gsl_odeiv2_step_rk1imp**, I get the error 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)' when I attempt to run it. Am I missing something?

Comment: For the implicit methods you have to provide the Jacobian matrix evaluation. At the moment there is a null pointer in the place of that function. -- You can also replace the `for(i=...` loop by `while(x<xf) { xi = x+dt; ...` to get the focus from the number of steps to the step size.

Comment: Hi Lutzl, Following is my code. I attempt to evaluate y'=x+2y between x=0 to x=1 with initial condition (x,y)=(0,0) using gsl_odeiv2_step_rk1imp. I defined the jacobian. However, the code is not running and throwing errors which I am unable to understand. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Lutzl, Please review:

```
 '#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_errno.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_odeiv2.h>

int odefunc (double x, const double y[], double f[], void *params)
{
    f[0] = x+2*y[0];
    return GSL_SUCCESS;
}


int  jac(double x , const double y[] ,double *dfdy , double dfdx[], void *params) {
    gsl_matrix_view dfdy_mat= gsl_matrix_view_array(dfdy,1,1);
    gsl_matrix *m= &dfdy_mat.matrix;
    gsl_matrix_set(m,0,0,x);
    dfdx[0]=2;
    return GSL_SUCCESS;
}
int main ()
{
    int dim =1;
    gsl_odeiv2_system sys = {odefunc, jac, dim, NULL};
    gsl_odeiv2_driver * d = gsl_odeiv2_driver_alloc_y_new (&sys,     gsl_odeiv2_step_rk1imp,1e-7,1e-7, 0.0);
    int i;
    double x0 = 0.0,  xf =1.0; /*al value */

   while(x<xf)
    {
        double xi = x0 + 0.25;
        int status = gsl_odeiv2_driver_apply (d, &x, xi, y);

        if (status != GSL_SUCCESS)
        {
            printf ("error, return value=%d\n", status);
            break;
        }

        printf ("%.8e %.8e\n", x, y[0]);
    }
    gsl_odeiv2_driver_free (d);
    return 0;
}
'
```

Comment: You should learn what the Jacobian matrix actually is. In the example, `dfdy` and `dfdx` are both 1×1 matrices resp. numbers.  --  `xi` is the next step after position `x` and should thus be set to `xi=x+dx`. The stepper/driver advances, if possible, `x` to the position `xi`